# Como listar nomes repetidos

Tags: mysql, sql

Como que faz para listar nome no banco de dados com nomes iguais
por exemplo listar todas pessoas com nomes Pedro.

```
create database agenda;

create table contatos(     
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    nome varchar(40),
    idade int,
    dataCadastro date
);
```

Comment: Poxa pessoal é sua uma duvida, não precisar colocar -1 no meu post

Comment: Depende, você considera o nome completo? Se tiver "Fulano de Silva" e "Fulano de Souza", o nome (Fulano) é igual, ou só é igual se considerar o nome completo?

Comment: Só um meio para fazer filtragem

Comment: por exemplo Fulano e aparecer todos fulanos

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que usar o comando SELECT

Ex: SELECT * FROM contatos WHERE nome='Pedro'

Basicamente seria "SELECIONE tudo da tabela CONTATOS ONDE o nome é igual a Pedro"

Você pode encontrar mais em: https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_select.asp

Mas assim, essa pergunta é extremamente básica, procura dar uma pesquisada sobre o básico de SQL.